# What does Yasuo's Wind Wall not block?

Tags: league-of-legends

It blocks everything from skillshots to even auto-attacks, but is there any skills that go through it? Things I have in mind would be dashes or certain attacks like Lux's ult.

How does it interact with returning spells (Ahri Q, Draven ult) or AOE spells. Do those spells still return to Ahri/Draven or just dissipate? Does AOE counter this wall such as Nasus or lux E's? Are bouncing projectiles blocked as they hit the wall?

Comment: Xeraths Q goes through it, and he is a good counter cause he locks him down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some Exceptions for the wind wall. Some of them are (most likely) bugs and others are projectiles that don't dissapear but just can't pass the wall.

List. Spells/auto attacks that are blocked are **BOLD** you can assume the rest is not blocked. If there is as spell with special behaviour I will point this out. The list would be too long if i counted every spell that doesn't get blocked.

Champions where no spell/AA can be blocked are *ITALIC*

- Aatrox **E**
- Ahri **Everything (R damage only)**
- Akali **Q**
- Alistar *none*
- Anivia **Q, AA, E**
- Annie **Q, AA**
- Ashe **AA, W, E, R**
- Amumu **Q**
- Blitz **Q**
- Brand **Q,E (if cast on ablaze target), R, AA**
- Caitlyn **AA, Q, E, R**
- Cassiopia **E, AA**
- Chogath **E (passive)**
- Corki **Q, R, AA**
- Diana **Q, W**
- Darius *none*
- Mundo **Q**
- Draven **Everything**
- Elise **Q, E, AA (Human form)**
- Evelynn **Q**
- Ezreal **everything (E damage only)**
- Fiddlesticks **E, AA**
- Fiora *none*
- Fizz **R (Fish won't dissapear, it just can't move through the wall)**
- Galio **Q, W**
- Gankplank **Q**
- Garen *none*
- Gragas **Q, R**
- Graves **Q, W, R (Projectile only, not cone), AA**
- Hecarim *none*
- Heimerdinger **AA, Q (AA), Turret (passive), W, E**
- Irelia **R**
- Janna **AA, Q, W**
- Jarvan *none (Q is ranged but it's a meele weapon)*
- Jayce, **AA(cannon stance), Q**
- Jinx **AA, W, E, R**
- Karma **Q, AA**
- Karthus **AA**
- Kassadin **Q**
- Katarina **Q, R**
- Kayle **Q, (AA are no projectiles, so they won't get blocked)**
- Kennen **AA, Q**
- Khazix **W**
- Kog Maw **Q, AA, E**
- LeBlanc **Q, E AA**
- Lee Sin **Q (Sonic Wave only), E(Cripple only)**
- Leona **E**
- Lissandra **Q, E, AA**
- Lucian **W, R, AA**
- Lulu **Q, W, AA, Passive**
- Lux **Q, W, E, AA**
- Malphite **Q**
- Malzahar **AA, Q**
- Maokai **Q, E (doesn't get destroyed but can't pass the wall)**
- Master Yi *none*
- Miss Fortune **AA, Q, R**
- Morgana **Q, AA**
- Nami **Q, E, R, AA**
- Natilus **Q, E (R not blocked. Maybe a bug)**
- Nidalee **Q, AA**
- Nocturne **Q**
- Nunu **E**
- Olaf **Q (stops moving when it hits the wall)**
- Orianna **AA, Q, E (the ball can't pass the wall and shield won't happen)**
- Pantheon **Q**
- Poppy *none*
- Quinn **Q, AA**
- Rammus *none*
- Rengar **E**
- Renekton *none*
- Riven **R**
- Rumble **E**
- Ryze **AA, Q, E**
- Sejuani **R**
- Shaco **E, W(AA)**
- Shen **Q**
- Shyvanna **E**
- Singed *none (Don't know if W is a bug because you can see the liquid mid air)*
- Sion **Q**
- Sivir **Q (will bounce back to Sivir), W, AA**
- Skarner **E**
- Sona **everything**
- Soraka **AA**
- Swain **E, R, AA**
- Syndra **R AA (Strangely E isn't blocked both orb and knockback. Maybe also a bug)**
- Talon **W, R**
- Taric **E**
- Teemo **AA, Q**
- Thresh **Q, W, E (His AA are connected to him and are no projectiles)**
- Tristana **E, R, AA**
- Trundle *none*
- Tryndamere *none*
- Twisted Fate **AA, Q, W**
- Twitch **AA, W, R**
- Urgot **AA, Q, E**
- Undyr *none*
- Varus **AA, Q, E, R**
- Vayne **AA, E**
- Veigar **Q, R, AA**
- Vel'Koz **Q, W, E** (his auto attacks aren't considered projectiles
- Vi *none*
- Viktor **Q (shield gets denied!), E, R (still moveable but DOT gets blocked), AA**
- Vladimir **AA, Q (Heal only. Damage still works), E**
- Volibear *none*
- Wukong *none*
- Xin Zhao *none*
- Xerath **AA, E**
- Yasuo: **Q, W(2 Windwalls will negate eachother)**
- Yorick *none*
- Zac *none*
- Zed **Q, W (Shadow stops at the wall)**
- Ziggs **Q, W, E, R (only when the bomb is visible so at start and end), AA**
- Zilian **AA**
- Zyra **AA, Range Plant AA, Passive, E**

For Items or special things Here's another list of things that get blocked:

- Caster minion AA
- Baron Nashor AA
- Dragon AA
- Deathfire Grasp
- Blade of the Ruined King
- Blackfire Torch
- Bilgewater Cutlass
- Mikael's Crucible
- Spoils of war (Shield lasthitting projectile)

Things that aren't blocked but still are projectiles somehow:

- Turret Hits
- Fountain Turrets
- Vilemaws Net attack

I'm pretty sure this list is accurate BUT there can be some mistakes after writing for 1 hour ;)

Comment: Wow that's thorough lol

Comment: About hecarim though, his ult sends those ghost-horsemen or whatever. Would those maybe be blocked but not his dash? And for Nautilus I don't think it's blocked because it isn't exactly a constantly moving projectile. As in it 'jumps' to its next location instead of a steady motion like everything else.

Comment: Since these horses are AOE they don't get blocked. If you look at things like Brands W or Annies W they also don't get blocked. It really has to be a projectile flying towards somehing.

Answer (score 5):

From lol wiki:

```
The wall blocks all enemy projectiles, except tower hits
```

This means anything that is a projectile including ults (even ziggs ult, because the bomb is actually flying over the map to the place where it lands).

Comment: Do you know if both side of the wall will block projectiles. Say I cast it in front of me while being chased, when I run through it will the backside of the wall still block for me?

Comment: @Katustrawfic I'm not sure about that. The animation looks like it will only block one way, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Both sides block it. And they block anything that is even considered a projectile, even if it is not currently flying through the air. I found this out, much to my chagrin, when playing Syndra. Her W animation involves spinning the ball around her before throwing it. When standing behind the wall, my ball was evaporated by it.

Comment: I would like to know about ahri/viktor proyectiles. Those that return to the owner.

Answer (score 3):

Dashes are no projectiles, so they go through. Dashes are, if at all, blocked by terrain and the wind wall is no terrain.
It does for example block Ashe ulties, like any other skillshot I have seen so far (since they are projectiles), even if they go through terrain. It also blocks targeted projectiles like Kayle's slow.
I suppose it would block a movement ability, if it were initiated by a projectile, kind of like Lissandra's, though I'm not sure the claw actually counts as a projectile. Imagine some new champion had a skill shot, that shot a projectile and wherever that projectile landed, the champion would dash there. The wind wall would probably cause that champion to dash to it that way. I think Leona's Zenith Blade does get blocked and she doesn't dash.

Yasuo's twice-charged Q gets blocked by the wind wall, I'm not certain about the previous uncharged Qs. They'll probably get blocked, but doing that is nigh-impossible: The cast time is so short, you need to deduct from his behaviour that he's going to use it and cast the wall in advance. But then the problem is that Yasuo needs to get fairly close for his Q, so if you cast the wall in advance, the wall has gone past him by the time he finishes casting it.
The wall can block projectiles all the way from it's spawn, not just when it's at full strength and distance, so if you get very lucky with your timing, you might hit it just right.

His wind wall does block Ahri's Foxfire as well as her Q. If it touches the wall on the way out, it's destroyed right there and won't return (Afaik. so far all Ahri Qs were always blocked right in front of them, so I'm not sure if they actually returned, but it didn't seem like it.)

Does anybody know, if the wall could block the lightning from items like the Statikk Shiv?

Comment: It does not block lightning from shiv, because that is not a projectile.