# Can Yasuo's W also deny "beam-type" spells?

Tags: league-of-legends

Suppose you play Xerath/Malzahar/Lux/etc. and shoot to the wall.

Since it is said that it stops **projectiles**, will the wall still stop these "beam-type" spells?

Also, assuming that Malzahar's ult can be denied, would he still be casting the spell or it gets cancelled ?

Comment: Xerath's Q and Lux's R are definitely not projectiles. Not sure about Malzahar's R.

Answer (score 4):

Think about it like this; Does the attack have a travel time to reach it's target? If so, than it is considered a projectile. Lux's Ultimate ("Final Spark") is considered an instant AoE, that just happens to be shaped like a laser beam. There are some things that are projectiles that the wind wall does not block, one example is Ziggs' Mega Inferno Bomb (Ultimate), for which the bomb travels over top of the wind wall.

Another good (Though not quite as reliable) question to ask is if the ability can be intercepted and taken by an ally. The general answer is that if yes, then the windwall can block it, however, there are a lot of exceptions to this one in both directions. Some projectiles, like all of Ryze's attacks except Rune Prison, are targeted spells, that produce projectiles that are block-able by the wind wall, but cannot be intercepted by an allied champion. As well, there are penetrating projectiles such as Caitlyn's Piltover Peacemaker that cannot be intercepted by an ally, but can be blocked by the wind wall.

All Ranged auto/basic attacks are blocked by the wall, Thresh's I believe is a glitch, as until recently his attacks were considered to be melee attacks for the purposes of Ravenous Hydra and Runaan's Hurricane.

Another thing to keep in mind is that certain projectiles are NOT destroyed upon contact with the wall. Such examples include Ziggs' Satchel Charge, Lux's Lucent Singularity, Orianna's ball, and Gragas' Barrel Roll. These will be blocked, but not destroyed. This is important to note, because the wind wall will NOT block the explosions/projected fields from these projectiles.

Answer (score 3):

No. He can only block "Projectiles". Projectiles are small objects flying towards a target.

Beams are connected to their caster and are not freely flying towards a specific place. You can basically say everything that's completely surrounded by "air" is a projectile (Ground Spells like Cho Gath Q don't count of course). He also cannot block Threshs auto attacks. They might be ranged but the weapon is still connected to Thresh with a chain.

I made a list about what can be blocked on [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146091/what-does-yasuos-wind-wall-not-block/147704#147704) thread.

Comment: "They might be ranged but the weapon is still connected... with a chain." This is also true of Thresh's Q (and Blitz's), yet it is still blocked by Wind Wall. This seems to suggest that it is more of a case-by-case basis that determines what is blocked.

Comment: What about Malzahar's ult? According to the list you did, looks like it traspasses the wall. Is that so?

Answer (score 0):

another hero that can penetrate yasuo's wind wall is velkoz(don't know his real name) ult as it penerates things. regarding malz ult, i think it won't be blocked as it is categorized as not a projectile, like urgot's ulti that still works if you're behind the "blocking" side of the wall