# Can Yasuo block thresh's basic attacks?

Tags: league-of-legends

Thresh's basic attacks are technically ranged since it works with runaan's hurricane. So does that mean that Yasuo wind wall can block.

Comment: This question already has an answer here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/147704/77408

Answer (score 4):

**No Yasuo's windwall will not block Thresh's auto attacks.**

Although they are ranged attacks, they are not **projectiles**. A Yasuo windwall will also not be able to block Vel'Koz's auto attacks since those are breams of energy (not projectiles).

Fun fact: Although the windwall cannot block the auto attacks of Thresh, it will be able to block the Runaan's Hurricane procs if thresh has one.